# Python While function

Tags: python, input, while-loop, conditional-statements

I was making a small game and for some reason this function won't work.

```
while InstructionsNeeded != 'no' or InstructionsNeeded != 'yes':
        print("please type yes or no")
        InstructionsNeeded = input("Welcome to Dice Brawl. Do you need instructions:")
        InstructionsNeeded = InstructionsNeeded.lower()
```

I offer the input before this in the code and it works perfectly fine. Also when I checked to see what the value was of InstructionsNeeded and it would read fine.

Comment: `InstructionsNeeded` cannot be both 'no' and 'yes' at the same time, so one of those ***or*** conditions is always true… Think it through.

Comment: "wont' work" in what sense? For example, you're currently missing an initial starting value for `InstructionsNeeded`.

Comment: I doubt very much it works fine. Your condition is always true, since no string can equal both `'no'` and `'yes'`. It should be `while ... and ...:

Comment: you probably just want to change `InstructionsNeeded != 'yes'` to `InstructionsNeeded == 'yes'`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `or` operator to `and` otherwise you end up with an infinite loop:

```
while InstructionsNeeded != 'no' and InstructionsNeeded != 'yes':
        print("please type yes or no")
        InstructionsNeeded = input("Welcome to Dice Brawl. Do you need instructions:")
        InstructionsNeeded = InstructionsNeeded.lower()
```